# replace content of a file from content of another file based on condition in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I've a two files
File1 contents:

```
<tag element="abc">
<util:cons path="com.rmn.STRING">
</tag>
<tag element="xyz">
<util:cons path="com.rmn.FLOAT">
</tag>
```

File2 contents(two space separated columns):

```
JAVA CHARACTER
PYTHON INT
```

Desired output is to replace Strings in file1 from file2.

```
<tag element="JAVA"> //replace string abc by JAVA
<util:cons path="com.rmn.CHARACTER"> //replace string STRING with CHARACTER
</tag>
<tag element="PYTHON"> //replace string xyz by PYTHON
<util:cons path="com.rmn.INT"> //replace string FLOAT by INT
</tag>
```

I'm not sure how sed or awk can be used in this case.

Comment: Have you looked into `m4`?  There is some old documentation in the [7th Edition Documentation](http://wolfram.schneider.org/bsd/7thEdManVol2/m4/m4.pdf).  Also, [Gnu m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/manual/m4.html) has a lot of extensions.  This isn't quite what you asked about, but it's good to know about if you're going to be doing a lot of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed is for simple s/old/new/ operations, that is all. You are not simply doing s/old/new/ so you should not be considering using sed. Just use awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR {
    tag[NR]  = $1
    util[NR] = $2
    next
}
/<tag/  { sub(/"[^"]+"/,"\""tag[++cnt]"\"") }
/<util/ { sub(/\.[^."]+"/,"."util[cnt]"\"") }
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
<tag element="JAVA">
<util:cons path="com.rmn.CHARACTER">
</tag>
<tag element="PYTHON">
<util:cons path="com.rmn.INT">
</tag>
```

The above will fail if the $2 values in file2 can contain backreferences (i.e. `&`). If that's an issue then update your question to include that.